# How to show lsusb result on different rows from a shell script?

Tags: linux, unix

I have not worked with Linux/Unix operating systems, but now I'm creating a script .sh.
   It is something like this:

```
echo "the usb devices mounted are: " `lsusb`
```

The result is not as when I ran same command from console (when I get all devices on different rows, like as a table), but it's only a line with all information on one single row.
   Could you help me with a hint in order to get the result (from the script) on different rows? Like the result I get when running it from console? Should I use a matrix? and parse it for each of its elements?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the command separately:

```
echo "the usb devices mounted are: " 
lsusb
```

Or as a oneliner:

```
 echo "the usb devices mounted are: " ; lsusb
```

Otherwise, you'll have to quote it as in the answer of @JoshJolly

Answer (score 0):

`lsusb` is being processed before `echo`, so the output will become arguments to `echo`, which will ignore any unquoted newlines. To see the output on separate lines, just include the command substitution in the quotes, or quote it separately:

```
echo "the usb devices mounted are: $(lsusb)"

echo "the usb devices mounted are: " "$(lsusb)"
```

Note that I have swapped the backticks for the `$(...)` syntax, which does the same thing but is more portable and can be nested.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
var=$(lsusb)
echo "the usb devices mounted are: $var "
```